# Site.getBaseUrl returns empty string in test method

Tags: apex, community, url

I'm writing tests for the community site controller class and I've faced with some problem.
When I invoke a controller method that includes *Site.getBaseUrl()* from test method I get an empty string. I launch the test as a community user. (*System.runAs*)

From [developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm):

> **Site.getBaseUrl()** 
>   Returns the base URL of the current site that references and links should use. Note that this field may return the referring page's URL instead of the current request's URL. The returned value includes the path prefix and never ends with a / character. If the current request is not a site request, then this field returns an empty string. This field replaces getCurrentSiteUrl.

getBaseUrl() **should** return smth like *mycommunity.cs44.force.com*.
URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost() returns *cs44.salesforce.com* there.

So, we can assume that it's not a Site request...
Does anyone know how to set it?

Test code example:

```
//getCommunityUser works properly
User objCmtyUser = Connect_TestDataFactory.getCommunityUser();
    Test.startTest();
        System.runAs(objCmtyUser) {
            Test.setCurrentPage(Page.Password_Reset);
            MyController ctrl = new MyController();
            ctrl.someMethod());
        }
    Test.stopTest();`
```

getCommunityUser Method:

```
    public static User createPortalAccountOwner(){
     UserRole portalRole = [Select Id From UserRole Where PortalType = 'None' Limit 1];
    Profile profile1 = [Select Id from Profile where name = 'System Administrator'];
    User portalAccOwner = new User(
        UserRoleId = portalRole.Id,
        ProfileId = profile1.Id,
        Username = System.now().millisecond() + 'test2@test.com',
        Alias = 'tesus',
        Email='test@email.com',
        EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',
        Firstname='Test',
        Lastname='user',
        LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
        LocaleSidKey='en_US',
        TimeZoneSidKey='America/Chicago'
    );
    Database.insert(portalAccOwner);
    return portalAccOwner;
}
 /*
 *@name getCommunityUser()
 *@return User 
 *@description This method creates Community User.
 */
public static User getCommunityUser(String Country,string countryCode,string lang,string Phone,string PersonHomePhone,string PersonMobilePhone,string fName){ 

   user portalAccOwner=createPortalAccountOwner();
    Account portalAccount=new Account();
    user communityUser=new user();
    System.runAs(portalAccOwner) {
        portalAccount.RecordTypeId='012U0000000ahJwIAI';
        portalAccount.FirstName=fName;
        portalAccount.lastname='2test';
        portalAccount.JobTitle__c='Veterinarian';
        portalAccount.Phone=Phone;
        portalAccount.PersonMobilePhone=PersonMobilePhone;
        portalAccount.PersonHomePhone=PersonHomePhone;
        portalAccount.Country_Connect__c = Country;
        portalAccount.Account_Country_Code__c = countryCode;
        portalAccount.BusinessEmail__c='test123@gmail.com';
        portalAccount.Account_created_for_portal_user__c=true; 
        portalAccount.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        insert portalAccount;

        Account tempAccount = [select id , personcontactid from Account where id=: portalAccount.Id LIMIT 1];

        //Create temp portal user
        communityUser.Email='test123@gmail.com';
        communityUser.Username='test123@gmail.com.mah';                
        communityUser.Professinal__c=true;  
        communityUser.ContactId = tempAccount.personcontactid;
        communityUser.ERP_Id__c='11111199299';  
        communityUser.Prof_Accnt_DataloadId__c='12345678901'; 
        communityUser.profileId=System.Label.CommunityLoginUserProfileId;                
        communityUser.Phone='12131231';
        communityUser.firstName='Asha';
        communityUser.lastName='Sharath';                
        communityUser.Alias='AshaS';                
        communityUser.CommunityNickname='AshaS'; 
        communityUser.Country2__c='USA2';                               
        communityUser.emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8';
        communityUser.localesidkey = 'en_US';
        communityUser.languagelocalekey = lang; 
        communityUser.timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
        communityUser.Country_Code__c=countryCode;
        communityUser.FederationIdentifier=communityUser.Username;
        communityUser.IsActive = true;
        communityUser.CampaignId__c='0';

        //insert new portal user
        insert communityUser;


    }
      return communityUser;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `getCommunityUser()` method? Or debug your user's role?

Comment: getCommunityUser method added

Comment: Have you tried `PortalType = 'CustomerPortal'` instead of having that be equal to `None`?

Comment: Yes, I have. Still getting the empty string. I have found something similar [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000092uPIAQ) There is no way to set community site in test context. We may use seAllData annotation instead.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I tried SeeAllData and it didn't work either.

Comment: Yes, you still cannot set the community site in the test context, but one of the workarounds would be write the following in the controller:
`if (!Test.isRunningTest())
{
 baseUrl = Site.getBaseUrl(); 
} else { baseUrl = 'mockedBaseUrl'; }`